# Governance Committee and Full Faculty

Tags: communication, governance

Part of my function is to head the committee that ultimately oversees the system of rules used in faculty governance.  I was wondering if anyone had experienced a governance system that was particularly effective in giving faculty time to consider upcoming issues and in amending or altering committee driven work in an effective manner?  I am wanting to increase the amount of deliberation external to committees, without slowing the process down significantly.  Still, I am looking for someone who has experienced a very effective rules structure or communication structure and who could share it.  We are a small private institution, but we are surprisingly formal in governance.

Comment: We had some luck in using a Wiki to do this, provided someone has the technical chops to set one up.  The benefit is multiple people can comment and provide feedback and everyone can see who's said what.  The only drawback we had to this system was that everyone commented at the last minute.

Comment: That is a really good idea.  It would also save on required meeting times.

Comment: Yep, exactly.  Just make sure everyone understands what a wiki is and how to use it.

Answer (score 3):

We had some luck in using a Wiki to do this, provided someone has the technical chops to set one up. The benefit is multiple people can comment and provide feedback and everyone can see who's said what. The only drawback we had to this system was that everyone commented at the last minute.

The most important and perhaps hardest part is making sure everyone knows what a wiki is and how to use it.  The specific problems we had were things like people printing things out and marking them up, people writing their own pages instead of working collaboratively, and the inevitable whole nuking of pages of work to make a minor change.  Just required being very clear and explicit, with examples.

Comment: Yeah, we have a couple of people who could do that.